Does the 5-verte wheel graph violate this iff condition on bridged graphs?
A couple of sources say the five-vertex wheel graph is not a bridged graph.

(Image from wikipedia)
According to wikipedia

The hereditarily cop-win graphs are the same as the bridged graphs.


The five-vertex wheel graph is cop-win but not hereditarily cop-win.

From On bridged graphs and cop-win graphs

COROLLARY 2.6. A connected graph G is bridged if and only if G is
cop-win and has no induced cycles of length 4 or 5.

Since a five-vertex wheel graph induces a cycle of length 4, it is not bridged.
However, On local convexity in graphs gives the following equivalence relation for bridged graphs.

Theorem 3.4. For any graph G, the following are equivalent:
(a) $N^j[K]$ is g-convex for any g-convex set $K$ and any $j$ > 0;
(b) $N^j[v]$ is g-convex for any node $v$ and any $j$ > O, and every 5-cycle in $G$ has a chord.
(c) $G$ is a bridged graph.

If we consider the axle vertex $v$ of the five-vertex wheel graph as $K$, the single vertex $v$ is trivially g-convex.  The neighbors of $v$, which gives the entire graph, is also g-convex.  By this theorem, the five-vertex wheel graph should be a bridged graph.
I'm quite convinced that the five-vertex wheel graph is not bridged, but where am I making a mistake?
(Admittedly, I'm having some trouble following the proof for Theorem 3.4 and Theorem 2.2 referenced)
